# Determine number of row in matrix

Tags: python-2.7

If I have a matrix, and a row, how can I determine the how many-th row it is in the matrix?

For example, if i got a matrix `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and I got the row `[4,5,6]`, then I want to know it's the second row a.k.a. `board[1]`.

(This is just a small example, but it is supposed to be checked on bigger matrices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the matrix (list of lists):

```
board = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
]
```

You can get its position by using [`.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> board.index([4, 5, 6])
1
```

Comment: Wooow, it was really that simple... Thanks!

Comment: @ruben_pants You're welcome. Since you appear to be new here, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)